# Network download speed halved

Tags: networking, router, lan, download, internet-connection

Past 2 weeks I have a problem with my download speed which got halved for some reason. It worked perfectly and I downloaded 2.4MBps without problems.

Our router has 4 Ports

1. PC
2. TV box
3. PC
4. WiFi router - 2 devices connected (which should be correct)

So, what I know:

- The provider said it's not the problem at their side and is probably within LAN.
- Websites as well as task manager reports 10Mbps download speed.
- A program called NetBalancer that shows Internet usage by program did not reveal any strange activity within my computer (I did that because of malware)
- Tested on a mobile device using network speed test displays correct (by correct I mean the speed I pay for) 20Mbps download and 2,5Mbps upload.

So I think it can be either malware or cable causing the problem. I am afraid it is the cable because Eset or the NetBalancer did not reveal any suspicious software.

Also very rarely Internet in my PC suddenly stops working, saying I have no connection and unplugging and plugging back in Ethernet cable fixes it.

Comment: "I am afraid it is the cable" so have you tried a new cable?

Comment: No. It goes through the ceiling so I want to be sure before I am going to change it. (it is pretty hard to change it) That's why I ask. Maybe there could be a different reason. Also, I ask to check if I did not overlook something and stuff like that.

Comment: Borrow or buy  a cable tester?

Comment: That is a good idea. So you agree it probably is the cable? (PS: I did not know that cable tester existed.)

Comment: I've no idea whether it is the cable, but it is certainly a possibility.

Comment: You mentioned two PCs in the setup. I couldn't figure out if both of them present the same issue. I'm assuming it is just one of them. I'd suggest you bring the PC that is working fine to the place where the other is, and switch them to test. If the other pc works fine, while connected to the cable of the first one, then you know it's not the cable. If it slows down the downloads as well, it's a strong indicator that it's the cable or the router/port in which said cable is connected to at the router. If so, try switching the ports to which they are connected.

Comment: Update: The port is the problem. I did not connect the other PC to the problematic PC's cable. I connected my notebook instead. The connection was halved. I switched the ports and the connection is back to 20 Mbps. So I need a new router. Thank you very much! ^,^

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this issue can no longer be reproduced.

Comment: I'd close it myself if I could. I could not mark the comment as the answer (or I don't know how) so I posted my own answer and I can accept that after 2 days... what a strange system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port is the problem. I did not connect the other PC to the problematic PC's cable. I connected my notebook instead. The connection was halved. I switched the ports and the connection is back to 20 Mbps. So I need a new router. Thank you very much for your help DavidPostill and Vinícius M! ^,^